# C program -special characters in output

Tags: c

Output of this program gives a special character in the beginning.Wat is the reason?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
main() {
    int i, j,count=0,nl;
    char str2[100];
    char str1[100];
    char str[100];
    char init[8];
    char final[8];
    //clrscr();
    printf("enter the bit string:  ");
    gets(str);

    puts(str);
    strcat(init,"10101010");
    strcat(final,"10101010");
    strcpy(str1,(strcat(init,str)));
    strcpy(str2,(strcat(str1,final)));
    puts(str2);
    printf("%d",(strlen(str2)));
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Do not use `gets()`.

Comment: `strcat()` must be used on initialized strings because before it can do its thing it must find the current string's end. Use `strcpy()` instead.

Answer (score 4):

You can't use `strcat()` on `init` because it's uninitialized, you need at least the `nul` terminator, example

```
init[0] = '\0';
```

but I would recommend `strcpy()` instead,

```
strcpy(init, "10101010");
```

would not require the initialization metioned above, but would require an extra character.

But then you need one extra character for the `nul` terminator, i.e.

```
char init[9];
```

instead of `char init[8]`.

Also, `gets()` is a deprecated function, because it has potential to overflow the buffer, you should be using `fgets()` instead, like

```
fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin);
```

Answer (score 3):

You need a `NUL` terminated string to use `strcat`

Change

```
char init[8];
char final[8];
```

to

```
char init[8] = "";
char final[8] = "";
```

And note that `gets` is deprecated, change to

```
fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin);
/* remove the trailing newline */
char *ptr = strchr(str, '\n');
if (ptr) *ptr = '\0';
```

Answer (score 0):

`strcat()` must be used on initialized strings because before it can do its thing it must find the current string's end. Since `init` and `final` are supposed to be empty, its best if you use `strcpy()` instead.

Also, strings in C are null-terminated, which means theres always an additional symbol `\0` at the end. Storing the string `10101010` actually takes 9 bytes. `init` and `final` can only take 8 bytes.

Also, you are trying to `strcat(init, str)`. `init` is already full at this point, so any additional `char` you are trying to append to it is out of bound and overwriting the stack. This application will invoke undefined behaviour and probably crash. `init` must be big enough to hold the content of `str` plus 9 bytes.